# Matrix converted from distance object, subset behaviour differs from normal matrices

Tags: r

If I create a matrix from scratch, I can subset it in various ways, retaining the column names:

```
tmp2 <- matrix(sample(9), nrow = 3)
colnames(tmp2) <- letters[1:3]

tmp2
     a b c
[1,] 1 3 8
[2,] 7 2 6
[3,] 5 4 9

tmp2[2, 2:3]
b c 
2 6 

tmp2[3, 1]
a 
5
```

In each case, the column names are retained in the subset. However, if I create a matrix by converting a distance object, the behaviour changes:

```
tmp <- matrix(sample(1:12), nrow = 3)
row.names(tmp) <- letters[1:3]
tmpD <- dist(tmp)
tmpDM <- as.matrix(tmpD)

tmpDM
         a         b         c
a 0.000000  9.848858  8.544004
b 9.848858  0.000000 10.099505
c 8.544004 10.099505  0.000000

tmpDM[2, 2:3]
      b       c 
 0.0000 10.0995 

tmpDM[3, 1]
[1] 8.544004
```

Notice that in the last example, the column name is dropped. This is a problem if I need the value of the cell and the name of the column in a calculation.

Why does this happen, and more importantly, how do I stop it? I need that column name, even when there's only one column in the subset.

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the second, there is row.names.  If we set it to `NULL`, then it should have the same behavior.  By default, the `drop = TRUE`, and what we get is a `named` vector.  When there are both row.names and column names, those attributes are dropped while `drop = TRUE`, because a named vector can have only a single name

```
row.names(tmpDM) <- NULL
tmpDM[3, 1]
#     a 
#9.539392
```

Just for a simple test, if we do the reverse, i.e set the column names to `NULL`

```
colnames(tmpDM) <- NULL
tmpDM[3, 1]
#     c 
#5.567764
```

Now, `c` is the `name` for that vector, which is the row name

These values are different as there was no `set.seed` and this is repeated each time from scratch

---

Or if we use `drop = FALSE`, it would have the `dim` intact

```
tmpDM[3, 1, drop = FALSE]
#        a
#c 12.92285
```

Comment: Wow, that works. Why?? Is there a reason for this? It's very surprising

Comment: @Tyler I updated the post. It could be related to the dropping of dimensions